# Как открыть Qt в Fedora 19?

Tags: linux, qt, fedora

Как открыть *Qt* в *Fedora 19*? После установки *Qt* я нажимаю на *QtCreator* и ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так?
Вывод терминала:[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: запустите программу *qtcreator* в эмуляторе терминала и приложите её вывод к вопросу (разумеется, в виде текста, а не картинки).

Comment: @alexander barakin изменил вопрос

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют. 2. проприетарный «драйвер» для видео установлен? попробуйте заменить его на свободный.

Comment: @alexander barakin какой драйвер? как ето определить?

Comment: @Тарас, ооой как хочется в гугл послать... Хотя нет, на википедию: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80